# How can I use `USING` clause with `LIKE` operator in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL in which I want to perform a search.
The PL/SQL is

```
DECLARE
      match_count INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
                  FROM all_tab_columns
                  WHERE table_name='GETS_TS_EGU_LOOKUP' and data_type LIKE '%CHAR%') LOOP

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||
          ' WHERE '||t.column_name||' = :1'
          INTO match_count
          USING 'NONE';

        IF match_count > 0 THEN
          dbms_output.put_line( t.table_name ||' '||t.column_name||' '||match_count );
        END IF;

      END LOOP;

    END;
    /
```

This PL/SQL can perform look up on the keyword **NONE**. I want to perform a `LIKE` search on **NONE** like **%NONE%**.

How can I do it?

Is it even possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||
  ' WHERE ' || t.column_name || ' like ''%'' || :1 || ''%'''
  INTO match_count
  USING 'NONE';
```

But with 'NONE' being a constant, why not simply:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||
  ' WHERE ' || t.column_name || ' like ''%NONE%'''
  INTO match_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a new variable to assign the string you want to search and then you cane use it in the query as shown below

```
    DECLARE
          match_count INTEGER;
         srch_str varchar2(20);
        BEGIN
          srch_str:= 'NONE'
          FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
                      FROM all_tab_columns
                      WHERE table_name='GETS_TS_EGU_LOOKUP' and data_type LIKE '%CHAR%') LOOP

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
              'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||
              ' WHERE '||t.column_name||' like ''%'||srch_str||'%'''
              INTO match_count;

            IF match_count > 0 THEN
              dbms_output.put_line( t.table_name ||' '||t.column_name||' '||match_count );
            END IF;

          END LOOP;

        END;
```

It will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Beware of SQL injection when accepting search strings from the user!